# Node.js grep process (but don't include self)

Tags: node.js, grep

So, from the docs, I can grep if a process exists or not. But if it doesn't, I get a returned result of self. I can do this by executing the actual statement, but what about node.js way?! I've tried multiple greps, but maybe somebody has already done this... I just need to add an extra `| grep -v |`, essentially.

```
var util   = require('util'),
    spawn = require('child_process').spawn,
    ps    = spawn('ps', ['ax']),
    grep  = spawn('grep', ['MyProcessThatIsNotRunning']);


ps.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
  grep.stdin.write(data);
});

ps.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
  console.log('ps stderr: ' + data);
});

ps.on('exit', function (code) {
  if (code !== 0) {
    console.log('ps process exited with code ' + code);
  }
  grep.stdin.end();
});

grep.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
  console.log(data.toString());
});

grep.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
  console.log('grep stderr: ' + data);
});

grep.on('exit', function (code) {
  if (code !== 0) {
    console.log('grep process exited with code ' + code);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not using [child_prosses.exec](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.8/api/child_processes.html#child_process.exec) ?

```
var cmdline = 'ps ax | grep -v grep | grep MyProcessThatIsNotRunning';
require('child_process').exec(cmdline, function (error, stdout, stderr) {
    if (error)
    {
        console.error(error); process.exit(1);
    }
    // parse 'ps ax | grep -v grep | grep MyProcessThatIsNotRunning' result here
    console.log(stdout);
});
```

Comment: Ended up doing something exactly like this, makes more sense.

Answer (score 0):

For the above answer you can try

```
var cmdline = 'ps ax | grep MyProcessThatIsNotRunnin[g]';
```

or

```
grep  = spawn('grep', ['MyProcessThatIsNotRunnin[g]']); 
//should work didn't test though.. :)
```

The square brackets is a trick to not find the grep.